# Why does Java give different answers for fractions with different parentheses

Tags: java, parentheses

I had to calculate this: 1*5000*500/(10000*24645.16239360158)

But then realized I should multiply it by 1000. I get 2 different answers depending on how I do it. I'm not sure why, though, as the placement of parentheses shouldn't matter for multiplication. Would appreciate any insight!

System.out.println(Double.toString(1000*1*5000*500/(10000*24645.16239360158)));

outputs

-7.283243937828597

for sure incorrect because it's negative

System.out.println(Double.toString(1000*(1*5000*500/(10000*24645.16239360158))));

on the other hand, outputs

10.143978603480635

(correct)

Basically in the second case we multiply the result by a 1000 after we've calculated it, and that somehow works.

Thanks!

Comment: `1000*1*5000*500` doesn't fit in an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this expression 1000*1*5000*500/(10000*24645.16239360158),first calculate 1000*1*5000*500,the result is -1794967296,overflow.

this expression 1000*(1*5000*500/(10000*24645.16239360158)) overflow do not happend.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know that `int * int` yields an `int` (`5 * 5`). And `int * double` yields an `double` (`5 * 5.0`).

As you probably know, those data types have different maximal sizes and store values in a different way.

Here are some of them:

[image]

You can use `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `Integer.MIN_VALUE` for the exact bounds.
If you need to exceed those values, but also want to have an `int`, you should use the class `BigInteger`. It can handle arbitrary big `integers`.
Else you will have what is called an `overflow`, when you do `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1` the result will be `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. If you recall how this number is stored in bytes, for example something like `111` then `+1` would return `1000` but there is no place to store the first `1`, you'll receive `000` which is the `MIN_VALUE`.

You also should know that when you compute `5 / 2` it will not return `2.5` but `2`, as you divide two `int`, the result will also be an `int`. If you want to have a `double`, then you need to do something like this `5 / 2.0` or `(5 + 0.0) / 2`.

Comment: Primitive type's MIN and MAX values is only one side of the problem. Operator precedence (multiplication before division, in this case), which you didn't address, is what's probably confusing OP, since they explicitly say `the placement of parentheses shouldn't matter for multiplication` when in fact it does.

Answer (score 0):

The evaluation of any expression is done by operator precedence parser. If you want to change the priority of precedence, You would've to use parentheses.

In the first case '/' and '*' having same priority [table](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

In second case '*' is getting some priority over '/'. Thats why your getting diffrent values as output.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of Java's implicit type casting. By default Java would use int. As user2357112 commented, the number is too large for int.

If you want your first version to work, add a "d" to tell Java to use a double.

Double d = 1000d*1*5000*500/(10000*24645.16239360158)
System.out.println(d);

You'd get:
10.143978603480635